# How to change the "search statements" in Unity lenses?

Tags: unity, lenses

When you open unity lenses you will see a `Search ...` in the search field.

For example application lens you will find *`Search Applications`* in the search field in the lens. Note the image...

[image]

- How could I change the statement to mine?
- Is it possible without recompiling the source code?!
- And could I use another language?!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

1. get the source code of the application.
2. Find and change the text with one you want.
3. compile and build the application.
4. uninstall previous lens and install your self compiled one.

Comment: Could you please include more detailed instructions

Comment: You will need to find exactly where the text is located to be able to replace it.Go to the forum/wiki/contact-email id of specific lens and ask the developers/users about it.alternately if you use a gui based compiler and development tool like Qt,you can also search for the text and then replace it.